# How to put text directly besides an image

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to place text beside images to recreate a gallery where people can see the price and name of a vehicle. The text should be placed right beside the image in order for it to look smooth. The problem I'm having is that I haven't been able to figure out how to place the text right beside the image without overflow and the usage of divs. Thanks for taking a look, I really appreciate it!

I have tried putting the text in the , putting it in sections and finally using

```css
.imgpers{
    margin: 20px 20px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}
.persOpties {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: right;

}
```

```html
<section class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Adam.jpg" alt="Opel Adam"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Astra.jpg" alt="Opel Astra"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/ComboL1.jpg" alt="Opel Combol1"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Corsa.jpg" alt="Opel Corsa"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/CorsaX.jpg" alt="Opel Corsa x"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Crossland.jpg" alt="Opel Crossland"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/MokkaX.jpg" alt="Opel Mokka"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</section>
```

Comment: The `<img>` should be **inside** the `<figure>` and the text should be inside a `<figcaption>` element.

Comment: What’s wrong with using divs?

Comment: a tyrant of a teacher declared using divs where too easy

Comment: and thanks i'll give it a try

Comment: Accordly with @Quentin comment, i'll suggest to read this [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

Comment: You shouldn't accept the first answer that comes along.  Make sure you really have the answer you need, and then wait a day before check-marking it.

Comment: thanks ray, you're totally right!

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```css
.imgpers{
    margin: 20px 20px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}
.persOpties {
    display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    align-items:center;
   -webkit-align-items:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: right;

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<section class="persOpties-main">
<div class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Adam.jpg" alt="Opel Adam"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</div>
<div class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Astra.jpg" alt="Opel Astra"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</div>
<div class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/ComboL1.jpg" alt="Opel Combol1"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</div>
<div class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Corsa.jpg" alt="Opel Corsa"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</div>
<div class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/CorsaX.jpg" alt="Opel Corsa x"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</div>
<div class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/Crossland.jpg" alt="Opel Crossland"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</div>
<div class="persOpties">
    <img class="imgpers" src="../media/opel/MokkaX.jpg" alt="Opel Mokka"><figure>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figure>
</div>
</section> 
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: yeah I appreciate you helping, but I can't use divs sadly

Comment: oh fine.. so move image to figure tag.. and add flex for figure

Comment: is this ok for you

Comment: This is just so wrong.  the "persOpties" ``div`` should be the ``figure`` tag.  The ``img`` should be inside the figure, not outside.  That's the whole point of a figure.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth :) :) :)